# Countdown timer from 10 to 0 in Unity

Tags: unity, c#, timer

I'm trying to make a countdown timer in Unity, and I've been able to make the timer count down from 10. However, I can't stop it at 0. I've tried putting it in a while loop but it didn't help, it actually made the timer start at 0.

```
float counter = 10.0f;
public TextMesh countdown;

void Start () {
    countdown = gameObject.GetComponent<TextMesh>();
}

void Update () {
    counter -= Time.deltaTime;
    countdown.text = "Time Left:" + Mathf.Round(timeLeft);

    if (counter <= 0)
    {
        Debug.Log("Hello");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because the update is called constantly, you're always running through this;

```
counter -= Time.deltaTime;
countdown.text = "Time Left:" + Mathf.Round(timeLeft);
```

and never really stopping.

In order to stop, you could try something like a flag- something to tell your loop when to stop the countdown. Though because of the simplicity of your program, you could try this, which doesn't use a flag but rather outputs the time left based on your current condition:

```
float counter = 10.0f;

public TextMesh countdown;

    void Start () 
    {
        countdown = gameObject.GetComponent<TextMesh>();
    }


    void Update () {

        if(counter > 0)
        {
            counter -= Time.deltaTime;
            countdown.text = "Time Left:" + Mathf.Round(timeLeft);
        }
        else 
        {
            Debug.Log("The counter has stopped.");
        }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with

```
void Update () {
    if (counter > 0) {
        counter -= Time.deltaTime;
        countdown.text = "Time Left:" + Mathf.Round(timeLeft);
    } else {
        Debug.Log("Hello");
    }
```

Note that this will print "Hello" in the console many time per seconds as soon as the counter reaches 0. This is what your code was doing, I don't know if it was on purpose.